# How to delete value in class in php (wordpress)?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, class, attributes

I need to remove 'wsqmylogin' which is inside class with if condition.
I tried all the folloing codes but it doesn't remove 'wsqmylogin'.
Would you please let me know how to delete it?

Existing Code:

```
<div class="elementor-column">
     <div class="elementor-column elementor-element-84c7af1 wsqmylogin" data-id="84c7af1" 
     data-element_type="column" id="my-checkout">
     </div>
</div>
```

Codes I tried:

```
<?php
$removeMyLoginJs = <<<EOD
<script>
    function myFunction() { 
        var element = document.querySelectorAll(".elementor-column");
        element.classList.remove("wsqmylogin");
     }
</script>
EOD;

$currentSlug = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];  
if(strpos($currentSlug,'order-pay') !== false){
    echo $removeMyLoginJs;
}
```

```
<?php
$removeMyLoginJs = <<<EOD
<script>
    function myFunction() { 
var myTbl = document.getElementsByClassName("elementor-row")[0];
var tSomeStyleClasses = myTbl.getElementsByClassName("wsqmylogin");
while (tSomeStyleClasses.length) {
tSomeStyleClasses[0].classList.remove("wsqmylogin");
     }
</script>
EOD;

$currentSlug = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];  
if(strpos($currentSlug,'order-pay') !== false){
    echo $removeMyLoginJs;
}
```

```
<?php
$removeMyLoginJs = <<<EOD
<script>
    (function myFunction() { 
        var element = document.getElementById("my-checkout");
        element.classList.remove("wsqmylogin");
     })();
</script>
EOD;

$currentSlug = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];  
if(strpos($currentSlug,'order-pay') !== false){
    echo $removeMyLoginJs;
}
```

Comment: Try : `document.querySelector(".elementor-column [data-element_type]").classList.remove("wsqmylogin")`

Comment: Hi Swati: Thanks for your advice and help. I tried it but still it doesn't remove 'wsqmylogin'...

Comment: Hi Swati: Thanks a lot for your help. I put this code before the div code creates. Thanks : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have access to the source code, you can try to delete that from the html/js file itself ;)

OOOOr if you really want to just delete it runtime, try to use element.parentNode.remove

Comment: Hi Shiuki: thank you for your comment. All codes have been created by plugin, so I'm using php to change them. And... I'm a newbie, very clumsy.. Would you please let me know how to deal with element.parentNode.remove? Thank you.

Comment: also any chance your php could be executed before the plugin creates that div?,
But parentnode is just the parent of the element  :sweat:. Don't listen to me I'm only confusing people. also if you want you can just hide it with css :3

Comment: Hi Shiuki: Wow, Wow, thanks a lot for your advice and comments. You were right, I didn't know the logic, I learnt a lot from you. Thanks again Shiuki : )